# CSS: Position element at bottom of page not window

Tags: html, css, css-position

The simplest html ever:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Some text content</p>
<p>Some more content</p>
<p> ... </p>

<img src="image.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

The image is intended to be positioned via CSS at the bottom of the **page**, behind the paragraphs.

Here's a live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/NfzT3/

Comment: This seems like a convoluted way of doing a `background-image`; why not just use a CSS background image?

Comment: That is why I did my code below. Repped. @Mathletics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. behind the text.. I think CSS via the body is better than solutions above - universal CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
}
</style>
```

If you want it fixed:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks - really simple but I hadn't thought of it myself

Answer (score 3):

Just add water. And this:

```
body { position:relative }
```

The image is positioned relatively to the next best positioned (non-static) element surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [Like this??](http://jsfiddle.net/NfzT3/10/) So that the image stays with the text rather than hitting the bottom of the window?

**I don't understand the repeated downvotes. The question clearly states "*bottom of page not window*" this is the only solution which does NOT align the image to the bottom of the window.**

Comment: There are three answers, two of which have a down vote. I wonder who would do that?

Comment: Well my answer and DanMans were posted at practically the same exact time. So There was no copying anyone else's answer. And regardless of how you feel about my reply, it's a valid, working answer. YOUR answer was actually the late answer here.